# SQL query results into separate columns on Excel worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, ado

Previously I was able to run some VBA that ran several SQL queries and put the results in separate columns in a single Excel worksheet. There was a reference set to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library (Tools, References in the VBE).

Although the code was working fine, recently I get an error message as follows -

Run-time error '-2147217913 (80040e07)'
Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Here is the code (the error appears in "rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic" which is less than helpful). Please note that the same error appears in all VBA/SQL code I try to run, not just the code below.

```
Private Sub GetUniqueClassesListWithConditions()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim strWkbPath As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim buf As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim iTimes As Integer
    Dim iQuestion As Integer
    Dim iCondition As Integer
    Dim iLimit As Integer
    Dim sCondition As String
    Dim iColumn As Integer

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    strWkbPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Worksheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    For iQuestion = 1 To 14

        For iTimes = 1 To 5

            Select Case iTimes

                Case 1
                iLimit = 7
                sCondition = "Day"

                Case 2
                iLimit = 6
                sCondition = "Time"

                Case 3
                iLimit = 16
                sCondition = "Faculty"

                Case 4
                iLimit = 13
                sCondition = "Department"

                Case 5
                iLimit = 6
                sCondition = "Student Numbers"

            End Select

            For iCondition = 1 To iLimit

                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT([Data$].Class) FROM [Data$] WHERE [Data$].Q" & iQuestion & " <> '-' AND [Data$]." & sCondition & "  = " & iCondition

                j = 0

                Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

                cn.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"

                cn.Properties("Extended Properties") = "Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"

                cn.Open strWkbPath

                Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

                rs.Open sql, cn, adOpenStatic

                ReDim buf(0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1, 0)

                For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

                    buf(i, 0) = rs(i).Name

                Next i

                Do Until rs.EOF

                    j = j + 1

                    ReDim Preserve buf(0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1, 0 To j)

                    For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

                        buf(i, j) = rs(i).Value

                    Next i

                    rs.MoveNext

                Loop

                rs.Close

                cn.Close

                Set cn = Nothing

                Set rs = Nothing

                iColumn = iColumn + 1

                With ActiveSheet

                    .Cells(1, iColumn).Value = "Q" & iQuestion & ", " & sCondition & "=" & iCondition

                    .Cells(2, iColumn).Resize(UBound(buf, 2) + 1, UBound(buf, 1) + 1).Value = TransposeArray(buf)

                End With

            Next iCondition

            iColumn = iColumn + 2

        Next iTimes

    Next iQuestion

    With ActiveSheet

        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True

        .Rows(2).EntireRow.Delete

        .UsedRange.Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit

        On Error Resume Next

        .Name = "Unique Classes List (Condtions)"

        On Error GoTo 0

    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

Private Function TransposeArray(buf)
    Dim tmp()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    ReDim tmp(UBound(buf, 2), UBound(buf, 1))

    For i = LBound(buf, 1) To UBound(buf, 1)

        For j = LBound(buf, 2) To UBound(buf, 2)

            tmp(j, i) = buf(i, j)

        Next j

    Next i

    TransposeArray = tmp

End Function
```

If somebody can help me get the code running and/or tell me what the problem is, I'd be very grateful.

Also, I'd like to do the same thing in Access. If I can export all of the results to an Excel file, even as different sheets in a workbook, it's easy for me to run some other code to combine the data into another worksheet. (I'm new to Access and know how to run SQL, but have no idea how to automate it, including putting the results in different "columns" and exporting it)

Should mention my SQL "skills" are basic and I'm learning from w3schools as I go along (hope I'm not offending anybody here.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What are the datatypes in the table [Data$] for the question and condition?

Comment: Know I'm probably not using the right terminology, but "numbers".

Comment: Data sent to me is sometimes iffy ("they" like to use text formatting in Excel because they don't know how to show leading zeros the "right" way). 

I did import the data into Access (fumbling newbie) and ran the SQL without problems. But I can only do it with one set of parameters at a time. If I could get the results for each time I ran the query into separate "columns" as the parameters change, that would be great. Or even exported to different sheets in Excel. I have code to consolidate the data.

Comment: Should mention that I've already solved this problem the "dumb" way within Excel, automating the autofilter and copying the results to another sheet but what I really want to know is how to do this with SQL, preferrably on it's own within Access possible. (Sorry for multiple comments but there's a number of characters limit)

Comment: You're saying in the SQL that the question is not equal to '-' (dash), which is a string/text.  But you say that the question is a number.  I think that's the datatype mismatch.  You can't compare a number to a string like that.  What are you trying to do with that criteria?

Comment: Sorry, the "question" part ( '-' ) is a string as you say.The "condition" part is a number.